# Scala and Chef -- most recent Scala packages

Tags: scala, chef-infra

I'm currently running Scala 2.11 on Ubuntu and looking to put together a chef recipe for some amazon instances, also on Ubuntu.

Running:
apt-cache show scala | grep -i version

Gives this output:

Version: 2.9.2+dfsg-2

Are the debian packages more up-to-date, typically?  Should I be using "dpkg_package" in chef as opposed to "package" in this case?

Eventually what I'm trying to do is put together  one or more cookbooks for scala w/ play, akka, sbt, and cassandra, so if you have resources that do part of that, that would also help.  (Sorry if that makes my question more vague, but I'm at the steep part of the learning curve).

Thanks!

John

Answer (score 2):

On the Chef side of this question, it just uses `apt-get install` so you get whatever apt says is the current version. I can't actually answer as to the quality of those packages, unless you setup a custom apt repository you are just getting whatever Canonical ships which is generally not the latest version.

Comment: Hi Coderange, thanks for that.  Yes, I figured that's what it was doing based on the apache2 example.  My question was more about best practices assuming one wanted to put together a more up-to-date stack.

Comment: If you're trying to get more up to date than the default repo, your best bet is to stick with `package` but have an earlier recipe in your runlist that adds a custom apt repo.

Comment: The only time I've needed `dpkg_package` over `package` is when I have a local package file already downloaded that I wanted to install. Otherwise, I think it's better to let `package` map itself to a provider automagically.